# CircularDependency on south

Tags: django, postgresql, migration, django-south

I have an app with an initial migration that has a foreign-key pointing to second app wich doesn't have south migration. Now i'm trying to add migrations to the second app, but i'm facing Circular Dependency errors.

I was able to migrate my production database, but i'm having trouble with syncdb --migrate on my database.

That's i have tried:

```
./manage.py convert_to_south app2

./manage.py app2 --auto
```

I want to restore my database after this and when I will try again

```
./manage.py syncdb --migrate
```

it doesn't work.

Comment: I need to migrate my second app and when I reset my database I try ./manage.py syncdb --migrate and it's fine.

Comment: You must create one migration only

Comment: No, I did it. I need another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this command first:

```
python manage.py schemamigration app_name --auto
```

Then:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Because you have already an existing migration for that you must delete the files and run something --delete--ghost--fake (I forgot the exact command) to delete the existing one.